# Does Java have an equivalent of a pump pattern to handle slow clients?

Tags: java

At the moment we have an architecture where a server streams data to the client.  We're finding instances where the client cannot process data quickly enough, the buffer overflows and the client is disconnected. Node.js has a pump pattern whereby a stream can be paused if data is not fully flushed and then resumed once the stream is drained. How would I do the equivalent pause/resume cycle in Java?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly the same thing, but it sounds like a variation on the producer/consumer theme to me.  Put a blocking queue between the two.  If the consumer can't keep up, the blocking queue continues to accept messages from the producer and accumulate them until the consumer is ready.

Or maybe you mean [this](http://jawk.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/jawk/jrt/DataPump.html).